# Update device token in iOS app for remoteNotifications

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have been developing an iOS app, which is sending remote notifications. For that I am saving the device token on our server. When the user logs in to our app, the device token saves on our server and remote notifications work fine.

But after some time, the notifications stop coming. I think it's due to that the device token changes but doesn't get updated on our server. I studied Apple's document on remote notifications; it says that if the device token ever changes, then it is the responsibility of the iOS to call the

```
 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

of the app delegate with the updated device token. I have written the code to save the device token to our server in this method, but the device token does not change and remote notifications do not come.

Do I have to update the device token myself? If yes, then where to do that?

Comment: probably the APN certificate expired?

Comment: I checked in the member centre the APN server is not expired